# Differentiating two trig functions. Check.

Tags: calculus

I have two problems that I'd like a quick checkup on. I am trying to differentiate these two functions:

1. $f(x) = x \cdot \cos x + 2\cdot \tan x$

and

2. $f(x) = e^x \cdot \cos x$

Here are my attempts:

1. Going to use a combo of sum and product rules.

$$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} (x\cdot cosx) + \frac{d}{dx} (2\cdot tanx)$$

$$= x\cdot(-sinx) + cosx + 2sec^2x$$

Is there anyway to simplify from here? It looks like I'm missing something...

2. $$f'(x) = e^x\cdot sinx + cosx \cdot e^x$$

$$e^x(\sin x + \cos x)$$

Here's another check:

3. Differentiate $y = sec\theta \cdot tan\theta$

$$= y' = sec\theta \cdot sec^2\theta + tan\theta \cdot sec\theta \cdot tan\theta$$

$$= sec^3\theta + tan^2\theta \cdot sec\theta$$

$$= sec\theta \cdot (sec^2\theta + tan^2\theta)$$

Comment: You missed a negative sign in part 2.  Otherwise I don't think there is any need to change anything.

Comment: Use a backslash \ before upright functions like `\sin` and `\log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps extending the steps will help. We have 
$$f(x) = x\cos(x) + 2\tan(x)$$

Then

\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}\left(x\cos(x) + 2\tan(x)\right)\\
&= \frac{d}{dx}\bigg( x \bigg) \cos(x) + x\frac{d}{dx}\bigg( \cos(x) \bigg) + \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(2\tan(x) \bigg )\\
&= \cos(x) - x\sin(x) + 2\sec^2(x)
\end{align*}
For the second we have

$$f(x) = e^{x}\cos(x)$$

Then

\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(e^{x}\cos(x)\bigg)\\
&= \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(e^{x}\bigg)\cos(x) + e^{x}\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\cos(x)\bigg)\\
&= e^{x}\cos(x) - e^{x}\sin(x)\\
&= e^{x}\left(\cos(x) - \sin(x)\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

First one looks good to me

Third differentiation is correct too.

Correct the second expression

$$(e^x\cos(x))'=e^x(\cos(x)-sin(x))$$

Comment: how about my newly added third?

Comment: @Jwan622 looks ok to me